# How to fill in a string in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, fill, isset

I'm trying to fill in a string in an array value that has a empty `''` 
do I need to use isset or empty to check it first?

Here is my code

```
echo table();

function table() {
    $a = array  ('0' => array('Jan de Boer', '213','440'),
                 '1' => array('Gerda Severin','214','442'),
                 '2' => array('Jean Dubois','215',''),
                 '3' => array('Peter Geringh','221','449'),
                 '4' => array('ricardo','666','666'));

    echo "<table border='6px'>
    <tr><th colspan='3'>Alle werknemers</th></tr>
    <tr><th>Naam</th>
    <th>kamer</th>
    <th >Toestelnummer</th></tr>";

    for ($x=0;$x<5;$x++){
        echo "<tr>";
        for($y=0;$y<3;$y++){
            echo "<td>",$a[$x][$y].'</td>';
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

It needs to fill in the blank `''` like a string unknown.

Comment: What are you replacing the empty string with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a check if the string is blank and replace with a value, in my example 'UNKNOWN'

```
    echo table();
function table()

{    
$a = array  ('0' => array('Jan de Boer', '213','440'),
             '1' => array('Gerda Severin','214','442'),
             '2' => array('Jean Dubois','215',''),
             '3' => array('Peter Geringh','221','449'),
             '4' => array('ricardo','666','666'));

echo "<table border='6px'>
<tr><th colspan='3'>Alle werknemers</th></tr>
<tr><th>Naam</th>
<th>kamer</th>
<th >Toestelnummer</th></tr>";

    for ($x=0;$x<5;$x++){
    echo "<tr>";
    for($y=0;$y<3;$y++){
    if($a[$x][$y] == "") $a[$x][$y] = 'UNKNOWN';
        echo "<td>",$a[$x][$y].'</td>';
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are checking for. `empty` will return true if the string is set and has no characters in it while `!isset` will only return true if the string does not exist at all.

If you are just trying to avoid errors and you are ok with a `''` string use `!isset`. If you are looking to make sure the string actually has anything in it use `empty`.